# NullPointerException while loading file

Tags: java, android, file

I am getting `NullPointerException` in the `LogCat` on this line:

```
File file1= null;
file1 =context.getFileStreamPath("GPS1.txt");
```

GPS1 does not exist when this code is executed. But that is not the problem, as a little way down in the code, I have a similar line:

```
File file2=null;
file2 = context.getFileStreamPath("GPS2.txt");
```

and this code does not throw any exception. GPS2 also does not exist at the time of execution. Both the code snippets are in the same function. What could I be doing wrong?

EDIT:
The relevant lines in the logcat are :

```
05-27 19:50:15.881: D/ java.lang.NullPointerException(994): tag
05-27 19:50:15.891: D/ java.lang.NullPointerException<!DOCTYPE html>(994): tag
05-27 19:50:15.891: D/ java.lang.NullPointerException<!DOCTYPE html>(994): [ 
05-27 19:50:15.931   994: 1292 D/error is java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.example.radio/files/GPS1 tag1
```

Comment: Neither of those lines will throw an NPE unless `context` is `null`. There is exactly one reason for an NPE - you have a reference value that is `null` and you try to dereference (call a method / access a variable / etc) it.

Comment: plz also add logcat results with question to get more help from us

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Added the LogCat lines..

Comment: The logcat you've posted is not being produced by the code you have posted.

Comment: @BrianRoach The last line contains GPS1, so at least it is being produced by the code I posted.

Comment: Oh ... right, because it contains something after that that *isn't* in the code you posted ... it must be!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that exception message is extremely clear:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.example.radio/files/GPS1`

This means that file `GPS1` cannot be found, i.e. does not exist (at least at path where you are looking for it). However `GPS2` seems to be existing file, so your program does not fail there.

Comment: But GPS2 does not exist! I checked in the file explorer in ddms and none of the 2 files exist!?

Comment: @AlexR Look at the exceptions again - it's obviously not from the code posted. It's saying that the file "GPS1 tag1" isn't found.

Comment: @BrianRoach it is from a Log.d() line. which is inside a try/catch block. tag1 is the tag used to filter messages in the logcat.

Comment: Here's the issue - you've posted code that has nothing to do with an NPE, then asked about an NPE. Then you posted a logcat that, only via ESP, would we know you're appending something to the exception. No one can answer this. If that's not the *actual exception* and you've manged the message, then yes, the file isn't found.

Comment: @BrianRoach If you can't answer doesn't mean others can't answer man. And you don't HAVE to answer, you know. Just go away.